# Getting selected datalist option value, and innerHTML, without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I have a situation where I want to let a user decide titles of books that I have on my db, using an input with a datalist (generated by php), after the user picked a title, he would click a submit button and the form would send the title in another file.

Everything worked fine but I didn't realized that I needed to send the ID of the book that the user selected, because there can be more than one book with the same title.

What I would like to have is the option of the datalist, that no longer has the title of the book inside its "value" attribute, but I want that title inside its innerHTML, so that the title gets displayed, while having the ID inside the "value" attribute. My problem is that if I do that, when the user clicks on the datalist option, the ID gets inside the text input, so the user may not know what book he choose.

**summing up:** I would like to have the datalist that displays the title, when an option is chosen, that title gets displayed in the text input, when I submit, the Id of the book gets sent in "FindBook.php" inside $_POST.

isIn() checks if the title is inside the array of titles, I would need to change that so that it can check if the ID is inside the array of IDs.

```html
<form onsubmit="alert(document.getElementById('number').value);" action="FindBook.php" target="_blank" method="POST">
      <input id="number" list="BooksById">
      <input type="submit" value="Find">
    </form>
    
<datalist id="BooksById">
      <option value="1">Title1</option>
      <option value="2">Title2</option>
      <option value="3">Title3</option>
      <option value="4">Title4</option>
  </datalist>
  
<br>

<form onsubmit="alert(document.getElementById('string').value);" action="FindBook.php" target="_blank" method="POST">
      <input id="string" list="booksByTitle">
      <input type="submit" value="Find">
    </form>
    
<datalist id="booksByTitle">
      <option value="Title1"></option>
      <option value="Title2"></option>
      <option value="Title3"></option>
      <option value="Title4"></option>
  </datalist>
```

Since I don't understand jQuery I would really prefer a solution that doesn't imply that.

Comment: Nothing changes!
`<form onsubmit="return isIn(document.getElementById('book').value);"`

Comment: Show isIn if that is the problem

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I don't think what you want is directly possible. As https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist says, _"Note: The <option> element can store a value as internal content and in the value and label attributes. Which one will be visible in the drop-down menu depends on the browser, but when clicked, content entered into control field will always come from the value attribute."_ The datalist doesn't have a value that would reflect the selected option, and I doubt the option elements themselves will have `selected` set either(?).

Comment: Only way I see under these conditions, would be to put id _and_ title into the options, with some sort of separator character. Then the user selection would cause the input field to get a value like `123:foobar`- which you can take apart, store the ID into a hidden field, and then change the text field content to be just `foobar` ...

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, I think that for now I will try your solution, I don't know if that's the cleanest solution but it should work just fine. From what I learned about datalists, the option tag is really minimal, you can't stlyle it and it does not have any useful attributes (I think), so I suppose there's no `selected` attribute.

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan too, there was an error in the code and you're right, the onsubmit condition does not change. isIn() works fine and I've added a snippet so that you can see how everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions. I prefer to use a datalist, instead of a select tag, because it looks more like a dropdown menu that works like a button. Using datalist allows me to find a book by a random word inside the title of it, while the select only finds the first word of an entry. I can also distinguish different books with the same name by another attribute that states if it's available or if it's taken.

**I asked for no JQuery**, i appreciate your help but I really don't understand them, even if it's cleaner to use them I would like a solution that doesn't use them.

I ended up using the solution CBroe suggested:

```js
document.getElementById("bookTitle").addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
 
  let data = this.value.split('');
  document.getElementById("bookId").value = "";
  if(isIn(data,'books')){
    document.getElementById("bookId").value = data[0];
    document.getElementById("bookTitle").value = data[1];
    
  }
});


function checkForm(id, value, list){
    if(isIn([document.getElementById(id).value,document.getElementById(value).value],list)){
      alert("Book found");
      return true;
    }else{
      alert("not found")
      return false;
    }
    }
     function isIn(value, list) {
      switch (list) {
        case 'books':
            //this was generated by php in my code
            if (value[0] == 1 && value[1] == "Title1"){
              return true;
            }
            if (value[0] == 2 && value[1] == "Title2"){
              return true;
            }
          return false;
          break;
          //I've cut out other cases
      }
    }
```

```html
<form onsubmit="checkForm('bookId','bookTitle','books')" action="FindBook.php" target="_blank" method="POST">
  <input id="bookTitle" list="booksByTitle" autocomplete="off">
  <label>id:</label>
  <input id="bookId" <!--type="hidden"-->
  <input type="submit" value="Find">
</form>
    
<datalist id="booksByTitle">
      <!-- value was generated by php in my code-->
      <option value="1Title1">Title1</option>
      <option value="2Title2">Title2</option>
  </datalist>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your case you must use a `<select>` tag instead of a `<datalist>` because you do not want the end user to enter new names (or yes?). However you can work with the data attributes like in the code below:

HTML:

```
<input list="titles" id="title-input" oninput="getBookId()">
<datalist id="titles">
  <option data-value="5" value="A book name">
</datalist>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getBookId() {
  var selectedTitle = document.getElementById("title-input").value;
  var value2send = document.querySelector(`#titles option[value='${selectedTitle}']`).dataset.value; // Here now you have the book title id.
  console.log("getBookId ~ value2send", value2send)
}
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* you can provide distinct title values for each datalist option...

Add a [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) attribute, such as `data-id`, to your [datalist option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) elements, containing the corresponding id, and add a `hidden` type input to your form. Then use the `onsubmit` event handler function to get the selected datalist option's dataset id value and assign it to the value of the hidden input:

```js
function findBook(form) {
  form.bookid.value = document.querySelector(`datalist option[value="${form.booktitle.value}"]`).dataset.id;
  console.log(form.bookid.value);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return findBook(this)">
  <input type="hidden" name="bookid">
  <input name="booktitle" list="BooksById">
  <input type="submit" value="Find">
</form>

<datalist id="BooksById">
  <option data-id="1" value="Title1">
  <option data-id="2" value="Title2">
  <option data-id="3" value="Title3">
  <option data-id="4" value="Title4">
</datalist>
```

Upon form submission, your PHP file will have the variables `$_POST['bookid']` and `$_POST['booktitle']` available.

Comment: Your `booktitle` is an `id` not a `name`, therefore won't send to `$_POST['booktitle']` surely?

Comment: This could select the wrong ID though, if _"there can be more than one book with the same title"_ means there could also be several options with the same text in the _same_ form instance.

Comment: @CanO'Spam Thanks for pointing that out. I changed `id` to `name`.

Comment: @CBroe If there can be more than one book with the same title, then I think datalist is not the appropriate mechanism to allow distinction between books with the same title. How can one show why one should choose "Homer's Odyssey" id 1 rather than "Homer's Odyssey" id 2 ? I assume there's some distinction, and if datalist is used that ought to be put in the `value` attribute.

Comment: I don't think it is realistic either, but since OP made a point to explicitly mention this, I figured they should be aware of what could happen in that kind of situation then. _Avoiding_ it to begin with (because it would not make much sense to the user either), I'll leave up to them ;-)